# Remove gridlines in ODS format with JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ods

Using JasperReports we can use the property `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.show.gridlines` in order to remove the gridlines in the exported excel file.

I'm looking for the same result in exported ODS files but can't find any corresponding property. Is there any option to achieve this goal?

Tried this code but it didn't work:

```
JROdsExporter exporter = new JROdsExporter();
SimpleOdsReportConfiguration config = new SimpleOdsReportConfiguration();
config.setShowGridLines(false);
exporter.setConfiguration(config);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: You have added correct property so it might be some bug from jasper side. Can you please log it in their issue list https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/issues?

Comment: Did you check if your classpath does not have any other version of jasperreport? https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/5880

Comment: Finally I got to think that OpenOffice/LibreOffice configuration regarding gridlines overrides the directive included in the document. I'm not working on that project anymore so I can't do more tests on this issue.